# How can I bind a column of different row length to a dataframe and copy the same values according to a matching date/variable in R?

Tags: r, time-series, aggregate, data-manipulation

I have rainfall and water level data for every 30 min interval (POSIXct format). I aggregated the rainfall data according to each day to get total daily rainfall. Now I want to add the total rainfall according to the same date to the original 30 minute interval data.

```
df$Date_Time<-seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2015-07-30 14:00:00",'%Y-%m-%d      
%H:%M:%S', tz="Etc/GMT-1"), as.POSIXct("2015-08-30 15:30:00",'%Y-%m-%d   
%H:%M:%S', tz="Etc/GMT-1"), by="30 min")
#Make POSIXct sequences and then some random variables for rainfall and water 
#level
df$PPT<-sample(seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.2), size = 1492, replace = TRUE)
df$WL<-sample(seq(from = -50, to = 50, by = 0.5), size = 1492, replace =    
TRUE)
df<-as.data.frame(df)
df$timestamp<- factor(strftime(df$Date_Time, "%Y-%m-%d", tz="Etc/GMT-1"))
dfag<-aggregate(PPT~timestamp,data=df, FUN = sum, na.action=na.pass)
#aggregate sums of daily rainfall.
```

However, I cannot find a way to bind the two dataframes (df & dfag) according to the timestamp (and copy the same daily rainfall values for the same date)

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to preserve the number of rows, use `ave` instead of `aggregate`:

```
df$PPTAggr<-ave(df$PPT,df$timestamp,FUN=sum)
#head(df)
#           Date_Time PPT    WL  timestamp PPTAggr
#1 2015-07-30 14:00:00 0.8  -7.0 2015-07-30      10
#2 2015-07-30 14:30:00 0.6  39.5 2015-07-30      10
#3 2015-07-30 15:00:00 0.6  13.5 2015-07-30      10
#4 2015-07-30 15:30:00 0.6 -49.0 2015-07-30      10
#5 2015-07-30 16:00:00 0.2  12.0 2015-07-30      10
#6 2015-07-30 16:30:00 0.6  34.0 2015-07-30      10
```

Comment: Also, `setDT(df)[, PPTAggr := sum(PPT) , by = timestamp]` or `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(timestamp) %>% mutate(PPTAggr = sum(PPT))`

Comment: Works like a charm. I like the ave option better. But both all three works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to merge by the timestamp variable:

```
# rename rain variable
names(dfag) <- c("timestamp", "dailyRain")
# merge data.frames
df <- merge(df, dfag, by="timestamp")
```